# How add,edit and delete node by line in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have string XML. I loaded to XmlDocument. How can I add, edit and delete by simplest method by line, because I know only line which I should edit. It's better work wih XML like with string, or better work with XmlDocuments?

```
    using System;
    using System.Xml;

    namespace testXMl
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<application>\r\n<features>\r\n<test key=\"some_key\">\r\n</features>\r\n</application>";
                XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
                xm.LoadXml(xml);
                //Edit third line
                //xm[3].EditName(featuresNew);
                //xml->"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<application>\r\n<featuresNew>\r\n<test key=\"some_key\">\r\n</featuresNew>\r\n</application>"

                //Add fourth line the Node
                //xm[4].AddNode("FeatureNext");
                //xml->"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<application>\r\n<FeatureNext>\r\n<FeatureNext>\r\n</features2>\r\n<test key=\"some_key\">\r\n</features>\r\n</application>"

                //Delete sixth line
                //xm[6].DeleteNode;
                //xml->"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<application>\r\n<FeatureNext>\r\n<FeatureNext>\r\n</features2>\r\n</features>\r\n</application>"
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *always* work with `XDocument`/`XmlDocument` objects. A key knowledge is the XPath query language.

This a quick XML crash course. Run with debugger and inspect the XML variable as you move on.

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version='1.0'?>
    <application>
        <features>
            <test key='some_key' />
        </features>
    </application>");

// Select an element to work with; I prefer to work with XmlElement instead of XmlNode
var test = (XmlElement) xml.SelectSingleNode("//test");
    test.InnerText = "another";
    test.SetAttribute("sample", "value");
var attr = test.GetAttribute("xyz");    // Works, even if that attribute doesn't exists

// Create a new element: you'll need to point where you should add a child element
var newElement = xml.CreateElement("newElement");
    xml.SelectSingleNode("/application/features").AppendChild(newElement);

// You can also select elements by its position;
// in this example, take the second element inside "features" regardless its name
var delete = xml.SelectSingleNode("/application/features/*[2]");

// Trick part: if you found the element, navigate to its parent and remove the child
if (delete != null) 
    delete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(delete);
```